# Using SL4a to make intent that adds new contact

Tags: python, sl4a

I need to construct a meaningful intent in python to add a new contact i.e name, phone-number-cell, phone-number-work, email.

So far i have the following template i have been trying to follow and modify but it doesn't work. I don't expect the contacts application to open at all for this but my app should show a sigle prompt to agree and done.

```
# Add to contacts

import android

droid = android.Android()

activity = 'Intents.Insert.ACTION'
type = 'ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE'
extras = {}
extras['Insert.NAME'] = 'GodfreyTest'
extras['Insert.PHONE'] = '435313****'

packagename =  ''
classname = ''

intent = droid.makeIntent(activity, None, None, extras, None, packagename, classname).result
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I just plugged in the values and i don't think it is right. I will edit the question.